# 1px border between floated and unfloated divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

The goal is to create grid with indented rows where the last cell fills to right hand side of the page with a 1px border around each cell.

The problem in the attempt below is that the border of the last cell of a row extends the full page width which creates unwanted borders around an indent. This seems strange because the div contents are correctly aligned.

http://jsfiddle.net/woqpq508/1/

```
    <style>
        .table {
            border-collapse:collapse;
        }
        .row {
        }
        .indent {
            min-width: 20px;
            float: left;
        }
        .cell {
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
            margin-left: -1px;
            margin-bottom: -1px;
            float: left;
        }
        .lastcell {
            float: none;    
        }           
    </style>

    <div class="table">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">x</div>
            <div class="cell">y</div>
            <div class="cell">zzz</div>
            <div class="cell lastcell" contenteditable="true">long text</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="indent">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="cell">x</div>
            <div class="cell">y</div>
            <div class="cell">zzz</div>
            <div class="cell lastcell" contenteditable="true">long text</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">x</div>
            <div class="cell">y</div>
            <div class="cell">zzz</div>
            <div class="cell lastcell" contenteditable="true">long text</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why do you use `float`? You can achieve what you want with `display:table/table-row/table-cell`.

Comment: @Vucko ideally cells would reflow in a narrow page but your suggestion is good. If you put this fiddle as an answer, http://jsfiddle.net/m0bm2vqh/1/ I'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment, you'd achieve what you want with `display:table/table-cell`.

```css
.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.row {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.indent {
  min-width: 20px;
  display: table-cell;
}
.cell {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  display: table-cell;
}
.lastcell {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">x</div>
    <div class="cell">y</div>
    <div class="cell">zzz</div>
    <div class="cell lastcell" contenteditable="true">long text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="indent">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">x</div>
    <div class="cell">y</div>
    <div class="cell">zzz</div>
    <div class="cell lastcell" contenteditable="true">long text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">x</div>
    <div class="cell">y</div>
    <div class="cell">zzz</div>
    <div class="cell lastcell" contenteditable="true">long text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle from your comment](http://jsfiddle.net/m0bm2vqh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could always draw a border around the row and only give each cell (except the last one) a `border-left`:

```css
.indent {
    min-width: 20px;
    float: left;
}

.cell {
    border-right: 1px solid;
    margin-left: -1px;
    float: left;
}

.lastcell {
    border: 0;
    float: none;
}

.container > div {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-top: 0;
}

.container > div:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <div class="cell">x</div>
        <div class="cell">y</div>
        <div class="cell">zzz</div>
        <div class="cell lastcell" contenteditable="true">long text</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="indent">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="cell">x</div>
        <div class="cell">y</div>
        <div class="cell">zzz</div>
        <div class="cell lastcell" contenteditable="true">long text</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="cell">x</div>
        <div class="cell">y</div>
        <div class="cell">zzz</div>
        <div class="cell lastcell" contenteditable="true">long text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you removed the float from the last cell, you've turned it back into a block element, which catches 100% of it's container (- other floats in your case).
Remove the lastCell class, and add clear:both to .row

```
    .row {
        clear: both;
    }
```

Anyhow, I must agree with the @Vucko comment - use a table or a css table instead.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this appears to make the last cell not extend to the right hand side of the page.

Comment: The last cell is floated, which means that it doesn't try to extend to 100% width. The .row clear: both just tells it to stop the float, and go down to the next line.